# How to autogenerate a Room database id without providing an id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am trying to create a room database and I want each item inserted into it to have its own unique id without me having to provide it, The problem is when I try to insert new items into the database I get an error asking me to provide an id.

Here is my entity:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
    data class Note(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "priority")
    var priority: Int)
```

Is there a way to have the database create its own auto-generated auto-increasing id column without having me having to add it like this:

```
    val item = Note(id, item, priority)
    insert(item)
```

And instead do this:

```
    val item = Note(item, priority)
    insert(item)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `constructor` that takes `item` and `priority` as arguments

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
data class Note (var item: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "priority") 
        var priority: String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0,
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply give the `id` a default value and put that at the end:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes_table")
data class Note(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "priority")
    var priority: Int)

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)    //must be at the end
    val id: Int = 0                     //Long type recommend
)
```

Then you can:

```
val item = Note(item, priority)
insert(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your data class `Note` has **three** parameter.

So you you have to create `Note` by passing **three** parameter.

It is nothing to do with autogenerate or room.

Comment: Should  I omit the id parameter? and if so, what happens if i want to delete or update a row in the database, will Room identify the specific row without an id column.

Comment: @DavidWekesa Yes. You can use other variable to generate your primary key, and use these primary key to find the object to delete or update a row.